# Update Root passwords via Shell

Tags: mysql, shell, mysqladmin

In a shell (.sh file) I'm trying to update the MYSQL passwords for user "root".

At the moment I have this, is this safe and the right way to do it?
I don't want prompts.

I'm also wondering whether the accounts of "mysqladmin" and "mysql" are the same.

```
#Variables for User and Pass
USER="root"
PASS="test"

mysqladmin -u root password $PASS
#Set Root User Password for all Local domains
sudo mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASS -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@localhost' = PASSWORD('secret');"
sudo mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASS -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('secret');"
sudo mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASS -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@::1' = PASSWORD('secret');"
#Drop the Any User
sudo mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASS -e "DROP USER ''@'localhost';"
```

**Update**

With the reactions of tadman and b600 in mind.

So something like this would be a good idea?

Preventing that passwords will show up in the shell history.

```
# bootstrap.sh
USER="root"
PASS="test"

sudo mysqladmin -u root password $PASS
sudo mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASS -e < /tmp/users.sql
rm -f /tmp/users.sql

# users.sql
SET @password = secret;
DELETE * FROM mysql.user WHERE users IS NOT 'root';

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@localhost' = PASSWORD(password);
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD(password);
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@::1' = PASSWORD(password);
```

Comment: `sudo -s` allows you to run multiple commands in a sub-shell, might clean that up a bit, or create a secondary script to reassign all passwords you can run once with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you generate the password hash on a local machine as a privileged user and pass the hash into the password change command.

According to [this page](http://albertech.blogspot.com/2011/08/generate-sha1-hash-from-command-line-in.html) the password hash used in mysql is `SHA1`, you can generate it using:

```
echo -n password | sha1sum | awk '{print toupper($1)}'
```

Also, according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html, you can use

```
'SET PASSWORD FOR 'user@domain' 'PASSWORD HASH GOES HERE' '
```

Personally, I don't like to have plaintext passwords on the command line at all due to the fact that an unprivileged user could potentially see the password via a ps/ptree/pstree command.

Comment: You should be using the [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function, not hashing it yourself. This uses SHA256 in newer versions of MySQL, so you're basically forcing bad behaviour to do it with SHA1.

Comment: If you use the PASSWORD() function on the command line, your plaintext password could be intercepted.  You could replace the sha1sum with sha256sum, and this would fix my previous command.

Comment: If someone's able to read the root user's shell history, you've got far bigger problems than your MySQL password.

Comment: I mean someone running a ps -auxwww which would show the plaintext password as the command was run, not the shell history.

Comment: That's a good point. I'd recommend writing out a `.sql` file that contains the commands to be run, then executing those with `mysql < init.sql` to avoid that.